# Python simple first_name last_initial when last_name could be blank

Tags: python, django

Working in django.

Creating unicode output for profile model, where user last name is optional.

```
Desired:
  John D. if last name
  John if not last name

Acceptable (though not ideal):
  John . if not last name
```

Current code:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %s." % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name[0])
```

This usually works to get the acceptable result, but fails when last_name == "".

Is there a one-line python idiom to generate my desired output?  I've searched google and stack overflow for a half dozen search terms and have come up goose eggs.

Comment: Easy way out: define a `format_name(fname, lname)` helper function that does what you want in many lines (i'd go with 3) and then just `return format_name(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)` in your `__unicode__`. That's one line where it matters (in your model), and readable to boot.

Comment: This is probably the best answer, want to put it in answer form so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way out:

```
def format_name(fname, lname):
    if lname:
        return "{0} {1}.".format(fname, lname)
    return fname
```

Then just `return format_name(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)` in your `__unicode__`. That's one line where it matters (in your model), and readable to boot.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
return self.user.first_name + (' %s.' % self.user.last_name[0] if self.user.last_name  else '')
```

The above is written as a one-liner since you've specifically asked for one. I personally would split it over two lines:

```
first, last = self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name
return first + (' %s.' % last[0] if last else '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s%s" % (self.user.first_name,
                     " %s." % self.user.last_name[0]
                       if self.user.last_name
                       else "")
```